# Python RecursionError

Tags: python, recursion

(I'm a total beginner)
I want to write a recursive function which can tell me if a number is a prime number or not: but I keep getting the same recursion error :
here is my code :

```
from math import *
def has_a_divider(n,p):
    if n%p==0:
        return True
    elif has_a_divider(n,(p-1))!= True:
        return False
    else:
        return False


def is_prime(a):
    if has_a_divider(a,sqrt(a))==False:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: There is a recursion depth limit in python [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Comment: `sqrt(a)` returns float, not int. Maybe you wanted to use `int(sqrt(a))`. It is not solving your problem, but it could improve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `sqrt(a)` which returns a float instead of the int your code requires.
You can replace it by `ceil(sqrt(a))` to get an int from it.

Also, this code does not work for finding if the number is prime as all numbers will have at least 1 has a divider. A possible solution is to update `has_a_divider` to check for dividers bigger than 1.

A possible implementation:

```py
from math import ceil, sqrt
def has_a_divider(n,p):
    if p < 2:
        return False
    if n % p==0:
        return True
    return has_a_divider(n,(p-1))


def is_prime(a):
    if a == 1:
        return False

    return not has_a_divider(a,ceil(sqrt(a)))

print(is_prime(3))
print(is_prime(5))
print(is_prime(4))
```

Comment: the __real__ issue (wrt/ infinite recursion I mean) is the lack of a guard before the recursive call - which your updated answer adds with the test on `p > 2`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. Let me disagree, if the input is an int there is an end case since at one point p will become one and `n % p` will always evaluate to 0. Additionally, dividers do not make much sense for floats. You can test it for yourself, remove the `p < 2` and run the code, you will *not* get infinite recursion.

Comment: I'm talking about the general case - making sure you DO have an end case in recursive calls. In this _specific_ case, forcing `p` to an int does indeed creates such a guard, but that's not the case for all recursive functions. This being said, since using floats as dividers don't make much sense in this context, you do have a point Sir ;-)

Comment: Then do you agree that your first comment is wrong in this instance since this answer is for this particular case where `has_divider` is expecting an int ? Or do you expect a function to behave appropriately in Python when the wrong type is given as parameter ? (Personally, I prefer the GIGO approach)

Comment: @Sylvaus I do agree that I was thinking in general terms and didn't fully analysed the consequences of forcing `p` into an int is this specific case, yes. I thought I made that point clear in my previous comment ;-)